# Form reset causes issues (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
$(function () {
    function f1() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('select[name=two]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('select[name=two]').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }
    $('input[name=one]').change(f1).triggerHandler('change');
    $('.reset').click(function () {
        $('input[name=one]').removeAttr('checked').end().click(f1);
    })
});
```

... almost works. Please check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mCT4U/).

But the problem is:

1. Check 'one' and select 'two' from dropdown.
2. Click 'reset'.
3. Check 'one' again and try selecting 'two' from dropdown.

Dropdown gets disabled automatically!

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Not a direct answer, but this feels a little too complex for what you're doing, esp. if the form grows in the future. Maybe storing the init. state with `clone()` would be better: http://jsfiddle.net/6HGsP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather trigger the change handler during reset. Replace

```
$('input[name=one]').removeAttr('checked').end().click(f1);
```

by

```
$('input[name=one]').removeAttr('checked').triggerHandler('change');
```

[Here's a new fork](http://jsfiddle.net/XfHKL/).